# Конвертация [object File] в array

Tags: javascript

Как можно преобразовать [object File] в array?
На входе имею файл с расширением .html и нужно его содержимое внести в массив в любом виде ( весь файл str в один элемент или же каждый символ в отдельный элемент)

```
<div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
  <output id="list"></output>


function handleFileSelect(evt) {
     evt.stopPropagation();
     evt.preventDefault();

var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.
    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
var output = [];
for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
    output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
        f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
        f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
        '</li>');
}
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}

function handleDragOver(evt) {
evt.stopPropagation();
evt.preventDefault();
evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
}

// Setup the dnd listeners.
var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
```

Comment: [object Filelist]  выдает при alert(files);

Comment: Так ведь у вас уже есть код работы с `files`. В чём проблема?